# Cannot remove file: Read-only file system

Tags: filesystems, mount, readonly

I am trying to delete a file on an Ubuntu 12.04 system for which I have root access. However, I am getting this error:

```
root@CRST-Web:/home/real_property/html# rm -r -f results.php
rm: cannot remove `results.php': Read-only file system
```

`df /home/real_property/html` output:

```
Filesystem                     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/CRST--Web--vg-root 121407596 65468436  49748876  57% /
```

I tried to remount the partition `rw` but it failed:

```
# mount / -o remount,rw
mount: cannot remount block device /dev/mapper/CRST--Web--vg-root read-write, is write-protected
```

Comment: Have you rebooted since getting this problem? if the root file system has errored to a `RO` state, it cannot be remounted `rw` while running. If the state has persisted through a reboot, then that information could lead to other potential problems.

Comment: It is a server running ubuntu 12.04. I will reboot the server and let you know.

Comment: Check `lvdisplay CRST-Web-vg/root` to see if the logical volume is set read-only. Actually check `lvs` as well, to see if (for example) you have a snapshot that filled up. I wouldn't recommend a reboot before figuring out why the roootfs has gone read-only—high risk of the machine not coming back from the reboot (hope this warning isn't too late.)

Comment: I rebooted the server and fsck automatically mounted the partition back to rw.